# How to Delete via DbSet in EntityFramework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

Hi I'm trying to write a generic repository for delete operation , this is my Repository

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IAggregateRoot
    {

        private readonly DbSet<T> _entitySet;
        private readonly StatosContext _statosContext;

  public Repository(StatosContext statosContext)
        {
            _statosContext = statosContext;
            _entitySet = statosContext.Set<T>();
        }

 public void Add(T entity)
        {
            _entitySet.Add(entity);
        }

  public void Delete(T entity)
        {
            _entitySet.Remove(entity);
        }
}
```

when I call Delete via a service method like this

```
public void RemoveContact(ContactViewModel contactViewModel)
        {
            var categoryView = new ContactViewModel { ContactId = contactViewModel.ContactId };
            var contact = categoryView.ConvertToContactModel();
            _contactRepository.Delete(contact);
            _contactRepository.SaveChanges();
        }
```

it Doesn't work because it doesn't find the entity 
how can I write Delete method in mt Generic repository ??

Comment: First fetch entity and then delete it.

Comment: How can I do that please?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.find%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

Comment: Or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.attach%28v=vs.103%29.aspx as answered by Khanh To.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your entity isnt attached yet.

Heres my generic repository, take a look how I do this

```
    public void RemoveOnSave(T entity)
    {
        try
        {
            var e = m_Context.Entry(entity);
            if (e.State == EntityState.Detached)
            {
                m_Context.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
                e = m_Context.Entry(entity);
            }
            e.State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            throw new RepositoryTrackingException(
                "An attempt was made to delete an entity you are already modifying, this may happen if you are trying to update using the same repository instance in two place", ex);
        }
    }
```

https://github.com/lukemcgregor/StaticVoid.Repository/blob/master/StaticVoid.Repository.EntityFramework/DbContextRepositoryDataSource.cs

Comment: thanks , now I got this Error Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries. what is the problem now ?

Comment: that's concurrency problem. Another process deleted the object

Comment: or you have multiple contexts in play... trap for concurrency issues

Answer (score 1):

if you're working with disconnected entities and you're sure that the entity is not tracked by the context (you should), you can write this simple code.

```
public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        try
        {
             _entitySet.Attach(entity);
             _entitySet.Remove(entity);
             _statosContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException e)
        {
             _statosContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins,entity);
        }
    }
```

RefreshMode has 2 possible values: ClientWins and StoreWins. What value to choose depends on your strategy. Here I assume that you're implementing "Last Record Wins" strategy